# Remove a background from an image without adding a class

Tags: html, css

please take a look [here](http://glamourina.pl/united-nude-womens-fold-deluxe-hi-ankle-boots/).
I have added the following code:

```css
.entry_blog a {color:#000;}
.entry_blog a:hover {background-color: #000;color: #FFD700;}
```

The text links work fine. However when you go over the images, you can see a black line appearing in the bottom of each image inside the `<div class="entry_blog singlepageentry" itemprop="articleBody">` div.

I cannot add any new class to the images links. If I could add an image to the images links, I could simply add a

```css
.entry_blog .newclass a:hover {background:none}
```

However since there is no such a possibility, does anybody know how, in this case, I can remove the background from the images inside the `entry_blog` div?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you use inline style, such as `<img style="background:none">`?

Comment: You can use jQuery remove function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as all your images appear to be standalone blocks, all you need to do here is set your `img` elements to `display` as block-level elements (using `display: block`). This forces them to fill the containing `a` element without leaving any gaps, fully hiding any background which may be underneath:

```css
.entry_blog a { color:#000; }
.entry_blog a img { display:block; }
.entry_blog a:hover { background-color: #000; color: #FFD700; }
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution work. Btw, what's the downside (if any) of having the images set to `display: block`?

Comment: @Pikk with your current design there wouldn't be any downsides, however issues may arise if you decide to position other images or text to the left or right of the images as these images would no longer be `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is sort of confusing.

The best method is to add `background:none` or `background:transparent` to `.entry_blog a`

You say you can't add any new style to image links. What does this mean?

Surely you can alter the CSS.

Comment: my apologies, I wanted to say (I corrected the question), that I cannot add a new class, not a new style. This means I can edit the CSS, but those images are automatically generated by a function in the Wordpress core files, and I don't want to edit the core files.